# notification not shown when app in closed in android 8

Tags: android

when testing on android 7.0 every thing works great.
but in android 8.0 the notification is shown only if the app is not closed.

what am i doing wrong?

this is the notification creation:

```
    int delay_mills = 20 * 1000;

    Intent intent = new Intent(SDLActivity.mSingleton, SDLActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.putExtra("app_notification",true);
    PendingIntent click_notification_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SDLActivity.mSingleton, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) SDLActivity.mSingleton.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("0", "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SDLActivity.mSingleton, "0")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("title title")
        .setContentText("content content")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(click_notification_intent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(SDLActivity.mSingleton, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SDLActivity.mSingleton, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay_mills;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)SDLActivity.mSingleton.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

this is the receiver:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
}
```

this is the declaration in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="org.libsdl.app.NotificationPublisher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create Method in your MainActivityand use AlarmManager to set alarm at specified time, and call the method in `OnCreate`

```
public void sharedpref(){

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,47);
if (calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) 
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
if (alarmManager != null) {
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}


 }
```

I'm setting my alarm at **09:47 PM**

**Step 2:** Create `BroadcastReceiver` to listen when the alarm happens

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
   notificationHelper.createNotification();

   }
}
```

I'm creating this class named `NotificationReceiver` and extends `BroadcastReceiver`, in `onReceive` there is Class named  NotificationHelper, don't confuse i will explain this Class for next steps.

**Step 3:** Create the Notification class

```
 class NotificationHelper {

 private Context mContext;
 private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001";

 NotificationHelper(Context context) {
 mContext = context;
 }

void createNotification()
{

Intent intent = new Intent(mContext , NotificationActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
        0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Content")
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
assert mNotificationManager != null;
mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());

   }
}
```

This class handles the notification

**Step 4:** Come back to **Step 2:** and call the Notification Class

```
NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
notificationHelper.createNotification();
```

Finally go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and register this

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver"/>
```

Just follow the steps